# Responsive design issue with iPad/Tablet using Bootstrap

Tags: ios, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap3 css/js files to make my html page responsive for all kinds of screens (iphone, android, tablets, ipad, desktop).

It works fine on desktop and mobile devices but it's not 100% correct on iPad/Tablet. There are 2 issues with iPad/Tablet:

```
1. Responsive image for Tablet/iPad is still not fit to screen
2. font size of the text is small
```

Is it default behavior of Bootstrap3 or am I missing something?

Comment: What font-size are you getting, and what were you expecting?

Comment: Can you post your code?